# Recursion: How many additions are needed to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number?

Tags: recursion, fibonacci-numbers, recursive-algorithms

If the Fibonacci numbers are given by $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$, find and solve a recursion for the amount of additions needed to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number.

I think i've figured out the recursion: $A(n) = A(n-1) + A(n-2) +1$. I'm just not sure how to solve this because of the +1. Am I correct in thinking that I can ignore the +1 and solve $x^2-x-1=0$?

Edit: 
$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} +1$
$a_{n+1} = a_{n} + a_{n-1} +1$

$-a_{n+1}+2a_n-a_{n-2}=0$
$-x^3+2x^2-1=0 => x=1, -0.6, 1.6$

Comment: If you have the recurrence $A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-2)+1$ you can subtract it from its translation $A(n+1)=A(n)+A(n-1)+1$ to get a homogeneous one: $A(n+1)=2A(n)-A(n-2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Obviously you can calculate $F_n$ with just $n-1$ additions, simply by using the recurrence formula by which the numbers $F_n$ are defined. Can you see why your method is so disastrously wrong?

Comment: If you mean that there are better ways of calculating the Fibonacci numbers, of course they are. But this an exercise where we're analysing the algorithm we got given in class, which assumes we calculate n-1 and n-2 for each number n recursively.

Comment: @TierraTelder You can calculate $F_n$ recursively without using such a huge number of additions.

Comment: Well, if the problem is given as you stated it, then the recursion is simply $A(n)=A(n-1)+1$. I can hardly believe your teacher would want you to contemplate an exponentially worse approach.

Comment: @TonyK See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3498379/272831). The issue is that you're not implementing the recurrence relation directly, in which case everything claimed makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear recurrence relations, one approach is to note that the general solution is the sum of some particular solution to the recurrence and some solution to the homogeneous recurrence.  If you can solve the inhomogeneous recurrence ignoring the starting values, you can use the starting values to determine what solution to the homogeneous equation you need to add to it.

In this case, your recurrence $A(n+1)=A(n)+A(n-1)+1$ has the constant solution $A(n)=-1$, so the general solution is $A(n)=-1+a\phi^n+b\psi^n$ and you evaluate $a,b$ from the starting conditions.